# dll initializer method

Tags: structuremap

what I need is to register concrete classes for certain event types in each dll.

```
public interface IDomainEventHandler<T> where T : IDomainEvent
{
    void Handle(T domainEvent);
}
```

I do not want to scan for the EventHandlers, due to getting same handler registered and executed in inherited classes again and again, but I would like an initializer method in each dll to be called in the structuremap bootsrapper.

so in each dll (module) I would include something like

```
    public void SetEntityEventHandlers()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
               {
                   x.For<IEntityBeforeUpdateEvent<Person>>()
                       .Add<PersonBizObj>();
                   x.For<IEntityBeforeUpdateEvent<Person>>()
                       .Add<EmployeeBizObj>();
//lets say I have a ManagerBizObj which inherits from EmployeeBizObj and I do not want it in the //event handler loop
         }
    }
```

so does StructureMap have a convenient way of doing this, adding an assembly (dll) wise initializer function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the Registry class to do this.  Each dll has a registry class that initializes the classes that it owns.  The StrucureMap bootstrapper adds each registry to the configuration.

http://docs.structuremap.net/RegistryDSL.htm#section1

- A.dll contains a FooRegistry class
- B.dll contains a BarRegistry class

Each of these registry classes has code that initializes classes that it contains. Something like:

```
 ForRequestedType<IRepository>().TheDefaultIsConcreteType<InMemoryRepository>();
```

The bootstrapper class has the following code:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
    x.AddRegistry<FooRegistry>();
    x.AddRegistry<BarRegistry>();
});
```

Comment: I am not sure, is subclassing "Registry" enough for it to be executed?

Comment: The bootstrapper will still have to add each registry.  See http://docs.structuremap.net/RegistryDSL.htm#section2.